# xslt order and grouping with for-each-group

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm trying to get my head over nested grouping and sorting while using `for-each-group`.
My idea is to order and group `item`s at first by `producer`. Then when I have this `producer` groups I'd like to sort each of them by `code`. However currently the order of `code` doesn't work as I'd like to. In following example the problem is with `item` with `code=01001-064-03`. It should be grouped together with all other `item`s whose `code` starts with `01001` but it isn't. If I move entire `item/code[text()='01001-064-03']` (the last one) to the beginning of xml then grouping works ok.

Please what is my issue here?

Thanks

```
<items>
  <change_date>#11.11.2020 7:42:13</change_date>
  <result>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-01</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-02</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>def</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>ghi</code>
      <producer>prod2</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>jkl</code>
      <producer>prod3</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>abc</code>
      <producer>prod3</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>def</code>
      <producer>prod4</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>ghi</code>
      <producer>prod4</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>jkl</code>
      <producer>prod5</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-03</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
  </result>
</items>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"    
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"  
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"  
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"    
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"  
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:same-product" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="left" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="right" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="leftParsed" select="mf:get-regexp-group($left, 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rightParsed" select="mf:get-regexp-group($right, 1)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="matches($leftParsed, $rightParsed)"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:get-regexp-group" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="groupNumber" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group($groupNumber)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="change_date"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="result">
    <data>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="producer">
        <xsl:sort select="producer"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="item[not(mf:same-product(code, preceding-sibling::item[1]/code))]">
          <xsl:sort select="code"/>
          <group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[fiddle example here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uT/9)

I'm using xslt `2.0` with `saxon-he 10.3`.

---

EDIT:

So as @michael.hor257k asked for better explanation I'll try to do my best:

Each `item` is product. This product has `producer` and has `code` (product code). I want to group all products of producer by `code`. However codes are not same for similar products so the similarity is matched by function `mf:same-product`. For example two similar products could be `01001-064-01` and `01001-064-02` here I check the first prefix `01001` and if it matches it means both products should be added to same group.

expected result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-01</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-02</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>01001-064-03</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>def</code>
      <producer>prod1</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>ghi</code>
      <producer>prod2</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>abc</code>
      <producer>prod3</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>jkl</code>
      <producer>prod3</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>def</code>
      <producer>prod4</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>ghi</code>
      <producer>prod4</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item>
      <code>jkl</code>
      <producer>prod5</producer>
    </item>
  </group>
</data>
```

Comment: With your nesting of two `for-each-group`, the inner attempt to pass in the `preceding-sibling::item` will not necessarily select an item in the `current-group()` of the outer grouping as the siblings are based on document order of the XML input and not on the order of the grouping population. So that might be a cause of the code not doing what you want. I still wonder whether you need to compare two items in the grouping, can't you just infer the relevant part of the `code` for each item and use that part in `group-by` or `group-adjacent`?

Comment: Can you give some idea how to do that? This grouping is new for me. Just keep in mind that two different producers can have similar product codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a composite `group-by` suffices:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"  
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="change_date"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="result">
    <data>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" composite="yes" group-by="producer, code => replace('[^a-z0-9].*$', '', 'i')">
        <xsl:sort select="producer"/>
        <xsl:sort select="code"/>
          <group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uT/10

That is XSLT 3 which Saxon 9.8 and later (e.g. Saxon 10) support, if you really need to do it with an XSLT 2.0 processor then a nested `for-each-group group-by` or a concatenated grouping key can achieve the same as the `composite` grouping key in the above XSLT 3.

Comment: Thank you again. I was trying the select by multiple attributes and I remember it was not working so I never thought that group will work. This solution from you is really simple. And just a question `preceding-sibling` can not be used like `current-group()/preceding-sibling...`?

Comment: You can use `current-group()/preceding-sibling::item` or `current-group()/preceding-sibling::*` of course, but the sibling axis is defined over a tree of nodes; depending on what you want to achieve that might make sense to navigate the siblings of the nodes in the current group, but it navigates in the input tree, not in the sequence of nodes. Thus with `<parent><a>..</a><b>..</b><c>..</c></parent>` and a `current-group()` of e.g. the `a` and the `c` element the expression `current-group()/preceding-sibling::*` would include the `b` element which is not part of the group.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea is to order and group `item`s at first by `producer`. Then when I have this `producer` groups I'd like to sort each of them by `code`.

If that's all you want to do, why isn't it sufficient to do:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="producer">
        <xsl:sort select="producer"/>
        <group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="code"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> I'm using `xslt 2.0` with `saxon-he 10.3`.

Actually, you are using XSLT 3.0.

Comment: because there is a postprocess of `producers`. Basically one producer can have multiple groups. Grouping is based on function `mf:same-product` so if `code` of onen item matches `code` of another then there should be a new group. And yes I was wrong about xslt version used.

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) explain in words the logic you want to apply and (2) add the expected result.

Comment: to me it looks like the sort or grouping in second `for-each-group` doesn't work properly.

Comment: You are giving us an example instead of a rule.